# Error after compiling kernel module: sys/syscall.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux-kernel, redhat, system-calls

I am implementing a kernel module that edits the `whoami` command after being inserted, I am compiling it with a Makefile which content is as follows:

```
obj-m+=holamundo.o
obj-m+=acumulador.o
obj-m+=cliente.o
obj-m+=intercept.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r )/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

and my module code:

```
#define MODULE
#define __KERNEL__
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include </usr/src/kernels/linux/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <asm/fcntl.h>
#include <asm/errno.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/dirent.h>
#include <linux/mman.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

extern void *sys_call_table[];
int (*orig_geteuid)(const char *path);

int hacked_geteuid(const char *path) {
return 78;
}

int init_module(void) {

orig_geteuid = sys_call_table[SYS_geteuid32];

sys_call_table[SYS_geteuid32] = hacked_geteuid;
return 0;

}

void cleanup_module(void) {
    sys_call_table[SYS_geteuid32] = orig_geteuid;
}
```

The problem I am facing is when I execute the `make` command I get the error:

```
/usr/src/kernels/intercept.c:9:25: fatal error: sys/syscall.h: No such file or directory
```

I am using the linux kernel 4.12.10 in RedHat 7.3

After removing `#include <sys/syscall.h>` from the code, I get the following error:

```
/usr/src/kernels/intercept.c:27:31: error: ‘SYS_geteuid32’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 orig_geteuid = sys_call_table[SYS_geteuid32];
                               ^
/usr/src/kernels/intercept.c:27:31: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/usr/src/kernels/intercept.c: In function ‘cleanup_module’:
/usr/src/kernels/intercept.c:35:17: error: ‘SYS_geteuid32’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  sys_call_table[SYS_geteuid32] = orig_geteuid;
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Building a module uses kernel source.  It should not be using include files from userspace.

Comment: files from userspace  ???

Comment: There is no `sys/` headers in the kernel. Not sure what you want to find there. Also, `#define MODULE` and `#define __KERNEL__` are wrong: these macros are defined by the kernel build system (KBuild) if needed. Including `/usr/src/kernels/linux/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd.h` using its **absolute path** looks suspicious. Isn't including `asm/unistd.h` sufficient?

Comment: @Tsyvarev ok I removed all that you commented #define MODULE #define __KERNEL__ and the include of /usr/src/kernels/linux/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd.h and it did not fix my problem

Comment: Did you remove the inclusion of `sys/syscall.h` which, as @Tsyvarev noted, cannot be `#included` from the kernel? If so, that would have at a minimum changed the error message you were getting.

Comment: @GilHamilton yes now the error message is other, I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

The constant you are looking for is `__NR_geteuid` which is defined in `asm/unistd.h`.

Comment: the program compiles without errors, but when I  try to insert the module  with: `insmod intercept.ko` the whole OS gets blocked and I have to restart the machine :(

Comment: In your init function, printk the address of sys_call_table and compare it to System.map.  Also, you do not show the module_init and module_exit calls.

Comment: how can i do this please ?